# How can I use rpmrebuild to programmatically change the contents of a file in an rpm?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a need to programmatically change the contents of all xml files in several rpms and repackage them with a one-up'd release number. I know I can do this using rpmrebuild by installing the rpms, editing the files at their installed locations and invoking rpmrebuild to rebuild with those changes. I'd like to not have to install all the rpms just to edit their files. I know rpmrebuild has a `--change-files` option but I don't understand how to use it based on the man page and the usage examples I've seen.

I'm hoping it could do something like this:

`rpmrebuild --package --change-files "<grep for contained .xml files and run a sed command to edit them in place>" package.rpm`

I such a thing possible without installing the rpm? Can `--change-files` be used to change the contents of a file in an rpm?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!